# Need guidance in dealing with null strings

Tags: regex, tcl

I have an expression like `/a/b/c.d/f.`
I need all the characters in between `/` or `.`. When I tried to split them using `split` command, I am getting  the result as `{} a b c d f {}`. How can I avoid these null strings? Is there a way to get this done using `regsub`?

Comment: Some real examples? between `/` and `.` there is many posibilities.

Comment: expression is something like /name1/name2.name3/name4." I have many "." and "/" in between and I am getting a null string for the leading and trailing "/" or "." if i use split command.

Comment: That's not an example. Give input and output of what you want.

Comment: input :  /name1/name2.name3/name4 and 

output {required} :name1 name1 name3 name4

Comment: What does name contains? letters and numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those empty strings (they're *not* nulls) are saying that there are *separators* at the start and end of the string. You'd also get them if you had two separators next to each other; the `split` command is really oriented towards dealing with records, not words in more “ordinary” text.

One of the easiest methods of extracting the non-separator parts (note: I've flipped the problem on its head here) is to use `regexp -all -inline`, which will return a list of all the matched things:

```
set pieces [regexp -all -inline {[^/.]+} "/a/b/c.d/f."]
```

Be slightly careful with this: if you have capturing sub-regexps, they'll also be returned when you're using the `-all -inline` options.

Answer (score 0):

Using regsub I got the required result. 
it is   "regsub -all {(/)|(.)} $a "\t" result"
this did not provide me with any null strings

Answer (score 0):

I've done 2 different ways:

1. [Matching and saving them](http://regex101.com/r/bE0nU8)
2. [Replacing it (no tcl exactly)](http://regexr.com?32niu)

I hope it helps you a lil bit,  if you want to add uppercase, use `A-Z` too.